# iOS didSelectRow and setString

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am created list of fonts via tableView , and when user tab any of  cells the string of font should be change according to the cells , But I don't know why my code does not work !
my tableview opens with UIPopOverViewContoller : here is my code :

.h

```
@interface FontViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource ,  UINavigationControllerDelegate>  {

        NSMutableArray *listOfFonts;

    }
@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSMutableArray *listOfFonts;
```

.m

```
#import "FontViewController.h"

#import "xxxAppDelegate.h"
#import "xxxViewController.h"

@implementation FontViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    listOfFonts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [listOfFonts addObject:@"font1"];
    [listOfFonts addObject:@"font2"];
    [listOfFonts addObject:@"font3"];
    [listOfFonts addObject:@"font4"];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //TableView Codes ....

    cell.textLabel.text = [listOfFonts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    xxxAppDelegate *appDelegate = 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    appDelegate.viewController.detailItem = [listOfFonts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];     
}
```

xxxViewController.h :

```
@interface {

 NSString *fontString;
    id detailItem;

}


@property (nonatomic ,retain) NSString *fontString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id detailItem;
```

xxxViewController.m :

```
@synthesize detailItem ,fontString;



- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem {

    if (detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        [detailItem release];
        detailItem = [newDetailItem retain];

        //---update the view---
        fontString = [detailItem description];
    }

}

//here is the custom font codes : (I am using special fonts which does not works with UIApplicationFont in app plist)


 (CTFontRef)newCustomFontWithName:(NSString *)fontName
                            ofType:(NSString *)type
                        attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
{

// the string of cell should be equal to the pathForResource:fontString for example font1 , font 2 ...

    NSString *fontPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fontString = [detailItem description] ofType:@"ttf"];

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fontPath];
    CGDataProviderRef fontProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)data);
    [data release];

/// blah alah blah 

}
```

Here is debugger messages  in setDetailItem

```
NSLog(@"fontString: %@, assigned: %@ in controller: %@", fontString, [detailItem description], self);

2011-10-02 23:12:57.036 Medad[558:10d03] fontString: (null), assigned: font1 in controller: < myAppViewController: 0x7078a30>
2011-10-02 23:12:58.015 Medad[558:10d03] fontString: (null), assigned: font2 in controller: < myAppViewController: 0x7078a30>
2011-10-02 23:12:58.475 Medad[558:10d03] fontString: (null), assigned: font3 in controller: < myAppViewController: 0x7078a30>
2011-10-02 23:13:00.365 Medad[558:10d03] fontString: (null), assigned: font4 in controller: < myAppViewController: 0x7078a30>
```

my problem is this line:
fontString this should be changed as cell selecting ...

```
NSString *fontPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:???fontString????? ofType:@"ttf"];
```

I would be grateful if somebody help me thanks

Comment: "my code does not work !" doesn't help, please explain where and what isn't working about it.  Provide error messages from GDB if possible.

Comment: there is no any bug and warning or crashing :) just when I select a cell the string does not change it means does not change the font

Comment: I would also make you note that you're setting detailItem to the NSString "font1" or others, so you can directly set the fontString property. There is not point to assing a string and then call [ description] to get the same exact string.

Answer (score 1):

Set breakpoints in various locations in your code, especially in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and `setDetailItem:` methods to check if they are called.

- If they aren't, you probably forgot to set the `delegate` of your UITableView (you may have set your viewController being the tableview's `dataSource` but forgot the `delegate`?).
- If they are, check in the debugger (or using `NSLog`) the values of the various objects to check if there are `nil` objects (sending a message to `nil` has no effect)

I would bet that you forgot to link the `delegate` outlet of your `UITableView` to the proper object (typically your ViewController). *If that's not the cause, we definitely need more information and you need to debug your code step by step using breakpoints and the debugger.*

Comment: the cell selecting is fine ! according to the `NSLog(@"cell selected: %@" ,[listOfFonts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);`

Comment: i think the main problem is  `NSString *fontPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fontString = [detailItem description] ofType:@"ttf"];`

Comment: Wow wow wow didn't see this line… but WTF with the `fontString = [detailItem description]` affectation right in the middle of a parameter passed to a method call?!? That's nonsense! Shouldn't you use the `fontName` parameter here?

Comment: what exactly should I do ? I am little novice ;) I thought the string of font should be change according to the cell selected

Comment: As far as I understand your code, the `newCustomFontWithName: ofType:attributes:` should only load a TTF font from the resources, not change the string. The changes of `fontString` is already done in `setDetailItem:` (and that's the right place to do it). Do what I suggest in my last comment and only pass the font name to the parameter that… expect the font name. _Do you really understand what you are doing here?!_

Comment: my code works fine ! I test with simple label , but the problem is how can I mention into the `pathForResource`

Comment: Sorry I really need this answer :(

Comment: Sorry I don't want to be rude but I already gave you the solution twice in my comments, explaining why it was wrong and what to change. It seems you don't have the basics in OOP, not understanding what you are writing at all, so I can't help more than I already did by giving the solution. No offense, but if you don't understand why doing such an affectation directly in the parameter is absurd and why writing this line of code is nonsense like asking a car to bark, you should probably start with the basics and an easier project/tutorial.

Comment: So what should I do ? would you please download the source code and solve this problem for me ?

Comment: Mc.Lover, i think you're mising the point of SO. It is meant to answer specific questions and even if sometime it's also useful to understand what's wrong on code, now you're asking us to basically fix your project.
AliSoftware is right, you just need to learn some basic things. Don't worry, you'll be ok, but getting other people writing code for you is not the way.